Equality Check with FSS
Suppose that we have a condition like checking whether rows and columns ($I, J$) of a matrix $\textbf{A} (\in m \times n)$ have been changed into ($I', J'$) or noting has been added/ removed.
How could we apply Function secret sharing, FSS IC gate, for this machine learning task (i.e., $I == I' \land J == J'$), in two party scenario and semi-honest adversary model.
I appreciate any assistance.

This question could benefit from clarification: What is "IC"? Why do you insist about using a particular (esoteric) technique for this task, and not something more standard in the MPC world? How are $I$ and $J$ represented? Are they secret shared? Does one of the parties know each in the clear? These make a big difference in an MPC protocol.

FSS gate for Interval Containment (IC) [E. Boyle 21] is a new building block for function secret sharing scheme with reduced size of keys. $I, J$ are sub matrices that are secret shared among two parties ($I = I_0 + I_1$).  In my scenario, trusted dealer has all inputs and does this secret sharing among parties.

Besides, what do you mean exactly here as more standard in MPC?
